# Split dataset of JPG and XML files into train and test set

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a dataset for an object detection algorithm containing pictures (.jpg) and corresponding .xml files containing bounding boxes.

I want to write a script that randomly splits the dataset into train and test set which means i have to make sure i allocate the jpg with it's corresponding XML to the same directory.

How should i edit the following code in order to fulfill this?

Also, is this the "best" way of doing this or is it better to split the dataset after xml-to-csv conversion or after generating csv to tfrecords conversion?

```
import shutil, os, glob, random

# List all files in a directory using os.listdir
basepath = '/home/bis/hans/bis/workspace/images/Synced_dataset'
filenames = []

for entry in os.listdir(basepath):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(basepath, entry)):
        #print(entry)
        filenames.append(entry)

filenames.sort()  # make sure that the filenames have a fixed order before shuffling
random.seed(230)
random.shuffle(filenames) # shuffles the ordering of filenames (deterministic given the chosen seed)

split = int(0.8 * len(filenames))
train_filenames = filenames[:split]
test_filenames = filenames[split:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option to me is to create two list of files (`filenames` for `jpg` and `xmlnames` for `xml`) in the correct order and one list of indices `indices=[i for i in range(len(filenames))]`.

Then you can shuffle your indices list :

```
random.seed(230)
random.shuffle(indices)
```

Finally, you create your train and test sets for both your `jpg` and `xml` files:

```
split = int(0.8 * len(filenames))
file_train = [filenames[idx] for idx in indices[:split]]
file_test = [filenames[idx] for idx in indices[split:]]
xml_train = [xmlnames[idx] for idx in indices[:split]]
xml_test = [xmlnames[idx] for idx in indices[split:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil, os, glob, random

# List all files in a directory using os.listdir
basepath = 'images/'
labelpath='label/'
filenames = []
xmlnames = []

for entry in os.listdir(basepath):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(basepath, entry)):
        print(entry)
        filenames.append(entry)
        
        
for entry in os.listdir(labelpath):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(labelpath, entry)):
        print(entry)
        xmlnames.append(entry)

indices=[i for i in range(len(filenames))]        
filenames.sort()
xmlnames.sort() # make sure that the filenames have a fixed order before shuffling
random.seed(230)
random.shuffle(indices) # shuffles the ordering of filenames (deterministic given the chosen seed)

split = int(0.8 * len(filenames))
file_train = [filenames[idx] for idx in indices[:split]]
file_test = [filenames[idx] for idx in indices[split:]]
xml_train = [xmlnames[idx] for idx in indices[:split]]
xml_test = [xmlnames[idx] for idx in indices[split:]]

print(file_test)
print(xml_test)
```

> so i followed the above advice(by Joseph) to add indices and then when we make test and train variables the exact same images and labels are added in the variables, hope this helps

Comment: It's better to add some explanations to describe what you mean and how this code answers the question

Comment: added the info , basically we are making sure that images and anotations are named exactly the same and then taking the exact filenames of both formats and embedding them into  train test